# paper-menu-button is not displayed inside a paper-toolbar

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am very new to Polymer and I was trying use a paper-menu-button inside a paper-toolbar, to reproduce what was shown by Kevin Schaaf on Polymer Summit 2015, but it turns out that the element is not shown. Bellow is my code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">

<dom-module id="input-header">
  <template>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button icon="mail"></paper-icon-button>
      <div>{{title}}</div>
      <paper-menu-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-input label="Thread name:" value="{{title}}"></paper-input>
      </paper-menu-button>
    </paper-toolbar>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'input-header',
      properties: {
        label: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

What Am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: <div{{title}}</div> should be  <div>{{title}}</div>

Comment: dont know weather this is the one causing error

Comment: In fact, fixing the div tag does not fix the issue. I have tested it locally and it does not make the paper-menu-button be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes are important. Also you don't have a paper-menu  with the dropdown-content class defined. I'm not sure about having paper-input???

```
<paper-menu-button>
  <paper-icon-button icon="menu" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>Share</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
```

Comment: @EronCastro if it works, and this is what you are using, please accept this answer, it's good stack overflow etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying. Using `paper-input` inside `paper-menu-button` which should show some items doesn't make point for me, but anyway, if you want to see `paper-icon-button` inside `paper-menu-button` you have to add dropdown-trigger class.

Code should be:

```
   <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button icon="mail"></paper-icon-button>
      <div>{{title}}</div>
      <paper-menu-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-input label="Thread name:" value="{{title}}"></paper-input>
      </paper-menu-button>
    </paper-toolbar>
```

paper-menu-button should have some dropdown content so that's why i don't get it.

Maybe use some wrap `div` around `paper-icon-button` and `paper-input` and set dropdown-trigger class to it

Comment: Thank you! I have added the changes and it now works!